# Display a copy password button only when the generate password button has been clicked and a password has been generated

Tags: javascript, button

I have 2 buttons for my password generator a 'Generate Password' button and a 'Copy Password' button.

Both work as they should but I would like the 'Copy Password' button to only be displayed when the 'Generate Password' button has been clicked and a new password has been generated

```js
// Assignment Code
// HTML elements
const generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
const characterID = document.getElementById('characters')
const passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
const numberID = document.getElementById('numbers')
const upperID = document.getElementById('uppercase')
const lowerID = document.getElementById('lowercase')
const specialID = document.getElementById('special-characters')

// Variables
let validCharacters
let password


// character types
const numberCharacters = '0123456789'
const upperCharacters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
const lowerCharacters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
const specialCharacters = '!@#$%^&*()-_=+<>'

// All logic for generating password

function createPassword() {
  let password = ''

  // Additional variables
  let characterTotal = parseInt(characterID.value)
  let passwordLength

  // Function determining password length
  if (characterTotal >= 7 && characterTotal <= 128) {
    passwordLength = characterTotal
  } else {
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Please select a valid range of characters between 8 and 128"
  }
  validCharacters = ''

  // Check to see if numbers are accepted
  if (numberID.checked) {
    validCharacters += numberCharacters
  }
  // Check to see if uppercase is accepted
  if (upperID.checked) {
    validCharacters += upperCharacters
  }
  //Check to see if lowercase is accepted
  if (lowerID.checked) {
    validCharacters += lowerCharacters
  }
  //Check to see if special characters are accepted
  if (specialID.checked) {
    validCharacters += specialCharacters
  }

  //Alert if no checkboxes are selected
  if (numberID.checked === false && upperID.checked === false && lowerID.checked === false && specialID.checked === false) {
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Please select at least one character type"
  }

  //For loop to generate password
  for (let i = 0; i <= passwordLength; i++) {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * validCharacters.length - 1)
    password += validCharacters.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber + 1)
  }

  passwordText.value = password
}

//Run event for generating password on click or "Enter" events
const btnClick = generateBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  createPassword()
});

const enterBtn = document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    createPassword()
  }
})


//Copy password to clipboard
function myFunction() {
  // Get the text field
  var copyText = document.getElementById("password");

  //Select the text field
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices

  //Copy the text inside the text field
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

  // Alert the copied text
  document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Password copied to clipboard"
}
```

```html
<section class="card-footer">
  <button id="generate" class="btn">Generate Password</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Copy Password</button>
</section>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you clicked, but the code was a mess.

Comment: You missed a `}` here:  `if (characterTotal >= 7 && characterTotal <= 128) {
    passwordLength = characterTotal`

Comment: Please add missing HTML. You can add a `hidden` attribute to the copy and change in `btnClick`:  `document.querySelector(".btn").hidden = false;`